# Add TabItem in tabcontrol at runtime using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabcontrol

Hi friends,                                                                                      i am new to silverlight app. i have created tabcontrol with 4 tabitem .Name of the tabitems  are like tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 . i need to add  one more tabitem at run item . it added successfully by following code

> TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
>   tabItem.Header = "tab5";
>   tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);

my problem is, tab5 added next to tab4 . but my requirement is ,it should added next my current selected tabitem .that is, if am in tab1 it should between tab1 and tab2 and so on.                     i have  searched in msdn and goggle didn't get anything.Possible give some guidance to get my solution. i don't like to use third parties control .Please guide me to finish this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TabControl` exposes a `SelectedIndex` property, this will tell you the index of the currently visible tab within the `TabControl.Items`, simply `Insert` after that index. For example:

```
tabControl.Items.Insert(tabControl.SelectedIndex + 1, tabItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
tabItem.Header = "tab5";
tabControl1.Items.Insert(tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1, tabItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabControl.Items.Insert(index, item)`